# 'if errorlevel' statement when in 'for findstr' loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been unsuccessful getting the following to work.  Everything works until I try to get the results of the 'findstr' in the 'for' loop.  Maybe there is a better way of doing this:  look for %subnet% in the masters.csv file.  If it finds it, set the MSS variable to the resulting value from the 'for'.  If it does not find a value, it will assign a static value (orphan).  Thanks in advance for any help!!

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
        set ip=%ip:~1%
        echo %ip% > ipaddress.txt
        pause
        for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ("%ip%") do set FirstThreeOctets=%%a.%%b.%%c
        @REM echo First three: %FirstThreeOctets%
        @echo off
        setlocal
        set subnet=%FirstThreeOctets%
        echo %subnet%
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('findstr /r "^%subnet%," "\\server\APPS\appname\updates\masters.csv"') do goto OrphanCheck
        @REM if errorlevel ==1 goto Orphan do set MSS=%%A
        @REM echo %MSS%
        @REM goto 64installcheck
    :OrphanCheck
        if errorlevel==1 goto Orphan
        Goto NoOrphan
        :NoOrphan
        set MSS=%%A
        Goto 64installcheck
        :Orphan
        set MSS=ORPHAN
        echo %MSS%
        pause
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: no errors.  It is just going to one or the other regardless of the error level.

Comment: `if errorlevel==1` is definitely not what you want. It's valid syntax, but compares the string "errorlevel" with the string "1". You want either `if %errorlevel%==1` (if you want to check for exactly the return value `1`) or `if errorlevel 1` (if you want to check for any return value greater than `0`).

Comment: Understood on the %errorlevel% now... however, it is still not choosing one or the other 'goto's depending on the %errorlevel%. I'm wondering if the errorlevel is not actually referring to the results of the findstr, since it is coming after the results of a 'do goto'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (
    'findstr /r "^%subnet%," "\\server\APPS\appname\updates\masters.csv"'
) do goto OrphanCheck
```

two things can happen.

If `findstr` does not find the string, code in for loop is not executed and the next line is reached, but this line does not have access to the errorlevel generated by the `findstr`, it sees the errorlevel (?) of the `for` command.

If findstr finds the string, the goto is executed but the same scenario happens.

When the line that checks the error level is reached, another problem raises

```
if errorlevel==1
```

is a valid construct, but it does not do what it seams. It is testing if the string `errorlevel` is equal to the string `1`. The correct sintax should be

```
if errorlevel 1 ....
```

or

```
if %errorlevel%==1
```

but as indicated, when the line is reached the errorlevel will not reflect the error of the findstr command.

And three lines later the next error.

```
set MSS=%%A
```

Once the `for` command has ended, its replaceable parameter does not have any value.

For a simplified version of your code

```
for /f "tokens=3-6 delims=.: " %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4"') do (
    set "ip=%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d"
    set "subnet=%%a.%%b.%%c"
)

>"ipaddress.txt" echo %ip%

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
    'findstr /b /c:"%subnet%," "\\server\APPS\appname\updates\masters.csv"'
) do (
    set "MSS=%%a"
    goto 64installcheck
)

set "MSS=ORPHAN"
echo %MSS%
pause
```

Comment: WOW!  It works, and is much, much more consolidated.  Thank you!